# Blank activity using ListView and Adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am learning to use ListViews with Adapters. 
The codes I am posting here are from one of the tutorials from 
[Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)
This is my class(Equivalent to MainActvity class in tutorial) in which I am intialising a ListView and providing data to adapter.

```
setContentView(R.layout.searchresultrowlayout);
  try {
        jsonarray1=searchscreen.searchresults();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> propertylist=new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ();

    for(int i=0;i<jsonarray1.length();i++){

        HashMap<String,String> propertymap=new HashMap<String,String> ();
        try {
            jsonobject=jsonarray1.getJSONObject(i);

        Log.d("json", jsonobject.getString("id"));
            propertymap.put("propertytype",jsonobject.getString("propertytype") );


            propertylist.add(propertymap);   

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }  

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);


    adapter=new PropertySearchArrayAdapter(this,propertylist);
  //      Log.d("adapter", propertylist.get(1).get("price").toString());
    list.setAdapter(adapter);  

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {


        }
    });
```

and this is my adapter class

```
public class PropertySearchArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
//public ImageLoader imageloader;


public PropertySearchArrayAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> d){

    activity=context;
    data=d;
    inflater=(LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}


@Override
public View getView(int position,View convertview, ViewGroup parent){

    View rowview=convertview;
    if(convertview==null){
                rowview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.searchlist_row, null);}

        //ViewHolder viewholder=new ViewHolder();
        TextView propertyType=(TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.propertytype); //propertytype


    HashMap<String,String> property= new HashMap<String,String> ();
    property= data.get(position);

    propertyType.setText(property.get("propertytype"));
    Log.d("adaptertext", property.get("propertytype"));

    return rowview;


}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}


@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
```

}

These are XMLs

```
 searchresultrowlayout
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</LinearLayout>
```

searchlist_row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >



<!-- Property type-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/propertytype"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"


    android:textColor="#040404"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

The other XMLs list_selector,gradient_bg.xml,gradient_bg_hover.xml I have taken from the [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) itself.

My problem is when I am pushing my activity which is supposed to show list view(by intent from previous activity on button click), the screen that appears is completely black and blank.
Please help me out.

Comment: There might be exception check stack trace and post if any..

Comment: Thanks for replying.I checked and there is no exception or any warning.

Comment: Are you sure your list contain data..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `ListView` to show the data your adapter must return the number of items it contains(or wants to show) with the `getCount()` method and not `0`(in which case the adapter will be considered empty and nothing will be shown):

```
@Override
public int getCount() {       
    return data.size();
}
```